# Insert into oracle table from CSV using python

Tags: python, oracle, csv, insert-into, cx-oracle

I am reading a csv file with 5 columns and push to oracle table

[CSV file Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkoNu.jpg)

I know there are lots of resources on this .. But even then I am unable to find a solution for my problem

Code to read the CSV to python :

```
 import csv
 reader = csv.reader(open("sample.csv","r"))
 lines=[]
 for line in reader:
      lines.append(line)
  print lines
```

Output :

> [['Firstname', 'LastName', 'email', 'Course_name', 'status'],
>   ['Kristina', 'Bohn', 'abc@123.com', 'Guide to
>   Capnography in the Management of the Critically Ill Patient (CE)',
>   'Registered'], ['Peggy', 'Lutz', 'gef@123.com',
>   'Guide to Monitoring EtCO2 During Opioid Delivery (CE)', 'In
>   Progress']]

Code to push the list to Oracle table :

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@tamans*****vd/Servicename')
ver=con.version.split(".")
print(ver)
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO TEST_CSODUPLOAD ('FIRSTNAME','LASTNAME','EMAIL','COURSE_NAME','STATUS') VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)",lines)
con.commit ()
cur.close()
```

I am getting the error :

**DatabaseError: ORA-01484: arrays can only be bound to PL/SQL statements**

Please help me solve the issue Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are trying to pass an array to a single insert statement. You have two options here:

1) Use a loop to insert each row separately:

```
for line in lines:
    cursor.execute("insert into ...", line)
```

2) Use cursor.executemany() instead to do an array insert

```
cursor.executemany("insert into ...", lines)
```

The second option is more efficient but you have to make sure that the type of data is consistent for each line. If you have a number in one row and a string in the next row an error will be raised.

The [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#loading-csv-files-into-oracle-database) gives more detail.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your answers :)
The issue got resolved once I changed 
from

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO TEST_CSODUPLOAD ('FIRSTNAME','LASTNAME','EMAIL','COURSE_NAME','STATUS') VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)",lines)
```

to

```
cur.executemany("insert into TEST_CSODUPLOAD(Firstname,LastName,email,Course_name,status) values (:1, :2, :3, :4,:5)", lines)
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Why did you create a new answer, though, instead of simply accepting the one I gave?

Answer (score 0):

That error means what it said [here](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_oracle/issues/36/ora-01484-arrays-can-only-be-bound-to-pl)

> This is not a bug. You are issuing a SQL query, not a PL/SQL statement and this sort of thing is not supported by Oracle. In this particular case you can simply pass the string. If you have multiple strings you will need to use a subquery instead. Look at the table() and cast() operators for inspiration!

You can also dump into a sql file and execute it.

Comment: Good point. Although in this case the OP is not issuing a query! :-)

Comment: Wow the solution of cursor.executemany is awesome!! i sould change my code!! @AnthonyTuininga how big might me the array? Beacuse i'm working with too many inserts. Are they respect the nextval an currval? thank u

Comment: The array can be as big as you like -- within the constraints of memory and the database itself, of course! I'm not sure exactly what you mean about nextval and currval. You can use those within your insert statement and they will behave as they do everywhere else.